# Search video with YouTube API on Android

Tags: android, arrays, json, android-studio, youtube-api

I'm trying to make a new application that will help people hear music together.
One problem I noticed is that the people need to get the YouTube code of each song or video they want to hear.

I kind of fixed this problem by using MySQL database with names and codes of songs, then all what the user need to do is to find the YouTube video and click on share with my application, it sends the link and the name of the video to the database and then users can search there for the song they want to play. However, I want to get rid of that, too.

Is there some way to search for a video on YouTube with the API?

I found this link to open source code on Google Developers https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#examples
But it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=eminem&type=video&key=<key>
```

Change the parameters to get what you actually need, but you need an API key from https://console.developers.google.com/ to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={your_key_here}&channelId={channel_id_here}&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=20
```

you can use above url for searching videos.

Comment: Hey, Thanks :) There is way to change the channelid to normal search on youtube? im not gonna let people search songs by the channel name... xD

Comment: @ShaharIlany https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list go through this link to find out more about search opration

Comment: You can api explorer: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&maxResults=25&q=surfing&_h=2&. If it helps please accept answer.

Comment: I got the help i was needed to from Avid, Thanks :) I will share my code for other people that got trouble with that too.